# Could not find lint-gradle-api.jar (com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle-api:26.1.2)

Tags: react-native, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

My React Native build quite suddenly fails with an error, in spite of working just fine a day ago with no changes that appear relevant.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong: A problem occurred configuring project ':react-native-document-scanner'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':react-native-document-scanner:classpath'.
   > Could not find lint-gradle-api.jar (com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle-api:26.1.2).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/lint/lint-gradle-api/26.1.2/lint-gradle-api-26.1.2.jar
```

Similar questions have been asked several times before, but the usual solution is to add `google()` to the `repositories` section. However

1. Our `repositories` sections already contain `google()`
2. `google()` already appears ahead of `jcenter()`

Snippet from `build.gradle`:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        // ...
        google()
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        jcenter()
    }
}

// ...

allprojects {
    repositories {
        // ...
        google()
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

It may or may not be relevant, though I certainly find it peculiar, that it looks to me like it successfully downloads the same thing for *other* dependencies:

```
$ ls ~/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.android.tools.lint/lint-gradle-api/26.1.2/*
/home/petter/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.android.tools.lint/lint-gradle-api/26.1.2/8c54aedfe9da66e64402de04883cee083c127a3b:
lint-gradle-api-26.1.2.jar

/home/petter/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.android.tools.lint/lint-gradle-api/26.1.2/f68c47a57523ed87b225532b98f2dd2ece9552bb:
lint-gradle-api-26.1.2.pom
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case, it's related with Fabric module,

My imported Fabric module's version was 0.5.2 (also have problem 0.5.1)

I solved this to downgrade Fabric module's version from 0.5.2 to 0.5.0

When build is success then the .jar file is created at .gradle/..

So I can use 0.5.2 version again,

I think it can be related with module's version

Comment: in my case was a command-line options, take a look into it https://stackoverflow.com/a/59376069/2238515

Answer (score 1):

Run the following command inside the android folder of your react-native project:

```
"./gradlew build --refresh-dependencies"
```

This way you can find which node-module has issue in build.gradle.
I found this issue was being caused bu react-native-share module. So I updated the version to 1.1.3 in package.json for react-native-share. 
The other alternative is to update the build.gradle file inside the /node-modules/react-native-share/android/ and move the google() above jcenter()

Answer (score 0):

As you said the usual solution is to add `google()` to the repositories section. This actually also applies here. 
You just need to go to your `node_modules` -> `react-native-document-scanner` -> `android` -> `build.gradle`
There, you need to modify buildscript part like the following:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'
    }
}
```

You probably have `jcenter()` above google. `google()` is the same thing with

```
 maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
```