# Could not find com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle:26.1.4

Tags: android, android-studio

I am Not able to generate apk can u suggest me find out a solution for me?

Could not find com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle:26.1.4.
Searched in the following locations:
    file:/C:/Users/hp/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/m2repository/com/android/tools/lint/lint-gradle/26.1.4/lint-gradle-26.1.4.pom
    file:/C:/Users/hp/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/m2repository/com/android/tools/lint/lint-gradle/26.1.4/lint-gradle-26.1.4.jar
    file:/C:/Users/hp/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/tools/lint/lint-gradle/26.1.4/lint-gradle-26.1.4.pom
    file:/C:/Users/hp/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/tools/lint/lint-gradle/26.1.4/lint-gradle-26.1.4.jar
    file:/C:/Users/hp/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/tools/lint/lint-gradle/26.1.4/lint-gradle-26.1.4.pom
    file:/C:/Users/hp/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/tools/lint/lint-gradle/26.1.4/lint-gradle-26.1.4.jar
    https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/lint/lint-gradle/26.1.4/lint-gradle-26.1.4.pom
    https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/lint/lint-gradle/26.1.4/lint-gradle-26.1.4.jar
Required by:
    project :app

Comment: open setting.gradle and take a lot at it:

include ":App"

Comment: sir dont mind i am a starter and don't find where is it setting.gradle and what should do here if u again suggest me then i will highly appreciate

Answer (score 1):

This was causing to me due to --offline parameter in command-line Options in Compiler. After I removed, solved it !
[image]